# Connect a wiimote

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to get a wiimote connected to my computer. For this I am using the wiimote package (*ros.org/wiki/wiimote*).

Here is what I did:

1. install package: `sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-wiimote`
2. install dependencies: `rosdep install wiimote`
3. make: `rosmake wiimote`
4. run wiimote_node.py: The first problem is here. The wiimote_node.py script does not exist in the wiimote package. According to this tutorial (*ros.org/wiki/wiimote/Tutorials/StartingWiimoteNode*) you need to execute `rosrun wiimote wiimote_node.py`. This doesn't work. I found out that the script was installed in /opt/ros/groovy/lib/wiimote/. So I executed it there: `python /opt/ros/groovy/lib/wiimote/wiimote_node.py`

Executing the wiimote_node.py script results in following error:

`python wiimote_node.py  Traceback (most recent call last): File "wiimote_node.py", line 87, in <module> from wiimote.msg import IrSourceInfo ImportError: No module named wiimote.msg`

Can anybody help me with this problem?
I tried the whole day to figure out whats wrong there. But i cant get it to work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56125/connect-a-wiimote/) by [miniME](https://answers.ros.org/users/4283/minime/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2013-02-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-02-24**:
I think this is a bug in the catkin build / installation, I created a [ticket here](https://github.com/ros-drivers/joystick_drivers/issues/49) and I'll look into it. Thanks!

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-03-13**:
Fix has been committed and will appear in ros-groovy-wiimote 1.9.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved the problem by downloading/building/installing the source:

1. Download source from `github.com/ros-drivers/joystick_drivers`
2. unzip `wiimote` folder into `/opt/ros/groovy/share/wiimote`
3. build and install:

`cd /opt/ros/groovy/share/wiimote`
`mkdir build`
`cd build`
`cmake ../`
`make`
`make install`

4. start wiimote node: `rosrun wiimote wiimote_node.py`

---

Originally posted by [miniME](https://answers.ros.org/users/4283/minime/) with karma: 36 on 2013-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1